Homeomorphism from unit ball to itself preserving norm
Problem: Let $B(0,1)\subset (\mathbb R^2, \lvert \cdot\rvert_2)$ be the open unit ball and let $f\colon B(0,1)\to B(0,1)$ be a homeomorphism. Show that if $(x_n)\subset B(0,1)$ is a sequence such that $\lvert x_n\rvert_2 \to 1$, then $\lvert f(x_n)\rvert_2 \to 1$.
Tip: Assume to the contrary and use compactness to pass to a suitable subsequence.
My issue: I'm mostly stuck on deciphering the tip we were given by the lecturer. What compactness are we referring to here, since the open unit ball is not compact? Is there a way to show this result without using this tip? Is the proposition true, or should it be the closed unit ball instead, in which case talking about compactness is reasonable?

The lecturer is referring to compactness of the closed unit ball. The sequence $(f(x_n))_{n=1}^\infty$ has a subsequence which converges to a point in the closed unit ball, and the goal is to show that it isn't in the open unit ball.

Doesn't this just follow from the fact that the norm $|\cdot |_2$ is continuous? Not sure why you need compactness here.

If $|f(x_n)|_2 \not\to 1$ then for some $\epsilon>0$ and some subsequence $n_i$ we have $f(x_{n_i})$ is in the compact unit ball $\overline{B(0,1-\epsilon)}$.  Thus for some subsequence $m_j$ of the $n_i$ we have $f(x_{m_j})\to x$. As $f^{-1}$ is continuous we have $x_{m_j}\to f^{-1}(x)$.  Now $|f^{-1}(x)|_2=\delta<1$, but $|x_{m_j}|_2\to1$, giving us a contradiction.

Here's a solution that doesn't exactly use the hint.


In a metric space $(M,d)$, if $C\subset M$ is closed, $K\subset M$ is compact, >and $C\cap K=\varnothing$, then $$d(C,K):=\inf_{x\in C,y\in K}d(x,y)>0.$$  Here if >$C=\varnothing$ or $K=\varnothing$, we observe the convention that $d(C,K)=\infty$.


Proof of $1$: Suppose not. Then for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exist $x_n\in C$ and $y_n\in K$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)<1/n$. By (sequential) compactness of $K$, after passing to a subsequence and relabeling, we can assume $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to some $y\in K$. Then $$\lim_n d(x_n,y)\leqslant \lim_n d(x_n,y_n)+d(y_n,y)=0,$$ so $$y\in \overline{C}\cap K=C\cap K=\varnothing,$$ a contradiction.
Let $f:B(0,1)\to B(0,1)$ be a homeomorphism. Let $g=f^{-1}$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $$K_n=\{\overline{B(0,r_n)}:n\in\mathbb{N}\},$$ where $0<r_1<r_2<\ldots$, $r_n\uparrow 1$, and where $$B(0,r)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|<r\}$$ is the open unit ball centered at the origin with radius $r$.  Each $K_n$ is compact. Since the pushforward of a compact set under a continuous map is compact, $g(K_n)\subset B(0,1)$ is compact. Let $C$ be the unit circle, which is closed.  Since $C\cap B(0,1)=\varnothing$, $g(K_n)\cap C=\varnothing$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore $d(g(K_n),C):=\delta_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by $1.$
If $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset B(0,1)$ is such that $\lim_n |x_n|=0$, then $$\lim_n d(x_n,C)=0,$$ where $d(x,C)=\inf_{y\in C}|x_n-y|=1-|x|$ for $x\in B(0,1)$. For any $\n\in\mathbb{N}$, fix $0<\delta<\delta_n$ and $m_0\in\mathbb{N}$ so large that $d(x_m,C)<\delta$ for all $m>m_0$.  For $m>m_0$, since $d(x_m,C)<\delta$ and $d(K_n,C)=\delta_n>\delta$, $x_m\notin K_n=g(B(0,r_n))$. This means $f(x_m)\notin B(0,r_n)$, and $|f(x_m)|\geqslant r_n$ for all $m>m_0$.  This means $$r_n\leqslant \lim\inf_m |f(x_m)|.$$  Therefore  $$1=\sup_n r_n \leqslant \lim\inf_m |f(x_m)| \leqslant \lim\sup_m  |f(x_m)|\leqslant 1,$$ so we have $\lim_m |f(x_m)|=1$.

The line where $K_n$ is defined is unclear. $n$ is already bound beforehand, but then you write ${\overline{B(0, r_n)} : n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which makes no sense since $n$ is already bound. I presume you just mean $K_n = \overline{B(0, r_n)}$?

"If $(x_n){n=1}^\infty\subset B(0,1)$ is such that $\lim_n |x_n|=0$" This should probably say "If $(x_n){n=1}^\infty\subset B(0,1)$ is such that $\lim_n |x_n|=1$"
